# Silverlight testing: Watin vs Selenium comparison

Tags: silverlight, testing, user-interface, selenium, watin

I was wondering how well these web test frameworks (Watin and Selenium) work for Silverlight UI testing.

Have anyone tried it on a project? Are Watin or Selenium well suited for Silverlight?.

Answer (score 4):

I can't talk to Watin or Selenium with Silverlight, but I have played with [White](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=white), which is a layer on top of the MS Automation Framework, and I have liked what I have seen thus far:

I should also add that we defer the majority of our UI behavior testing to unit tests using the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx) pattern.  It doesn't test EVERYTHING, but it gets us 95% of the way there.

Functional testing frameworks like Watin/Selenium/White should be used in conjunction to unit tests.

Comment: Sounds interesting, will start taking a look at this.

Comment: I've used WatiN in a very basic way to kick off opening Silverlight pages and interacting with them through script, but -not- UIA.

Comment: Please could you update your answer to provide a link to the 'MVVM framework'?

Answer (score 2):

What about the [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) included in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)?

Here's [Scott Gu's intro](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/04/02/unit-testing-with-silverlight.aspx)

Not sure if this suits your needs, but I always like to check out the solution from the source itself!

Comment: This framework (yes, I designed and wrote it :-)) is meant more for unit testing and simple functional testing, rather than interactive UI testing.

Comment: I guess I can take your word for it > D

Answer (score 1):

I've not had the need to use it myself, but I have noticed that there is a Silverlight Selenium project 'Silvernium', which might be of interest to you. http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [WebAii](http://www.artoftest.com/) to hook into Silverlight. You can create NUnit/MSTest tests to drive them. I did find a number of bugs in it but they have released a number of versions since so assume they have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://www.artoftest.com/community/blogs/09-05-14/Automating_Real_World_Silverlight_Apps.aspx