# How can automation testing on Silverlight using Selenium be done?

Tags: silverlight, automation, selenium-rc

I am looking for a way by which I can automate my application build on Silverlight.

I need to use Selenium as required, can anyone tell a process or any good tutorial by which I can achieve what I require.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/

and

[Silverlight testing: Watin vs Selenium comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302385/silverlight-testing-watin-vs-selenium-comparison)

Also bear in mind that Silverlight's future looks uncertain:

http://www.hightechnewstoday.com/apr-2011-high-tech-news-archives/74-apr-13-2011-high-tech-news.shtml and http://www.electronista.com/articles/11/11/09/microosft.may.axe.silverlight.after.major.release/

etc. etc.

So you may prefer to consider HTML5 for future projects after completing your current Silverlight project, as HTML5 has a brighter future because of its cross browser support and efficiency compared with proprietary technologies like Flash and Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but its a old project and i just need to automation testing. thanks for your help and advice. Will surely keep that in mind.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate that legacy code has to be maintained. The 2 links I gave should be of help, at the very least to inform you as to some things that are available even if these aren't suited to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Sikulix which a desktop automation tool using which you can automate almost everything. which uses text interpretation of image so that us can locate your component.
If you are using python selenium i suggest to use pyautogui which is nice python package to automate silverlight web pages.