# Automatic UI testing in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, testing, automation

I want to automate the SilverLight Application for which i require to know the SilverLight Controls. But also i don't have the XAML file. Is there any way so that i can find the controls and can do the automation testing??

Comment: Have you searched anything in google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224943/how-can-automation-testing-on-silverlight-using-selenium-be-done

Comment: Yes of course but not able to get the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/)? Maybe it will be able to automate your SilverLight app. In the [Automa Console](http://www.getautoma.com/docs/console_commands) there is the **get_name_under_mouse()** function which returns the name of a control under the mouse cursor (if it can read it).

Comment: Wow... it's really looking great and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the VisualUIAVerify tool which can be used to get all the UI Elements and their properties required for Automation

Download link http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/

Comment: The tool is good which u have shared but it is not able to identify the silverlight application elements.