# How can I check that a Silverlight video is played with Selenium

Tags: c#, silverlight, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following problem:

I have a video on the page. The video is played with a Silverlight and I wanted to test it automatically with Selenium. Up till now I have only seen how to test flash videos with Selenium.

One of the few posts regarding [Selenium and Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224943/how-can-automation-testing-on-silverlight-using-selenium-be-done) does not look very promising.

Is there a way to do such sort of testing with Selenium? All I need is to know that the video started to play.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, not with Selenium anyway.

But for automating Silverlight, you can try [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White).