# How do I control the browser file upload dialog using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, file-upload, upload, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a tool that automatically submits files to a website using Selenium and ChromeDriver.

Usually uploading files is easy with Selenium since you can just give the information to the `<input type="file">` element. However, in this case I am working with a website that has a custom file upload button, there is no `<input type="file">` anywhere on the page and the upload happens instantly after selecting a file in the file upload dialog (like this):

[image: Browser upload dialog]

Therefore, my only option is to have Selenium click on the custom upload button and control the file dialog. But I can't figure out how to do this. How do I use Selenium to control the OS/browser file upload dialog?

I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164558/trigger-file-upload-dialog-box-on-radasyncupload-control-using-selenium-webdrive) which doesn't seem to apply to me because they have `<input type="file">` on the page and are trying to trigger the upload dialog, but I do not have that element and I do not have a problem triggering the dialog, my problem is with controlling the dialog once it's open. I have also read several questions on SO about uploading multiple files and none have information that can help my situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829153/selenium-drag-and-drop-from-file-system-to-webdriver

Comment: What binding language are you using with Selenium? I mean what coding language are you using?

Comment: @Prophet I'm using C#

Comment: @ScriptDeveloper This website doesn't have a drag-and-drop area for files. It is a button (`<button type="button">`) that triggers some JS that opens a file dialog.

Comment: You could try using AutoIt along with C# to try to upload files.

Comment: I need clarification before I give a try. After you selecting the file, do you see any attribute value is changing in DOM? because I believe the value should be stored somewhere.

Comment: @NandanA No, nothing changes in the DOM. When a file is selected, it's instantly uploaded, the contents are displayed on the site, and the file path doesn't exist anywhere in the DOM. This is for Connecticut's government website for annual withholding tax forms so unfortunately it's not something most people could give a try. I apologize if it seems like an impossible challenge but I was really hoping there was a way to just grab control of the file dialog itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I hope this work for you too:
You can set the value of your input field using JavaScript.  Considering that the id of the field is `fileName` the following example will set the value of the input to the file `C:\temp\file.txt`:

```
String script = "document.getElementById('fileName').value='" + "C:\\\\temp\\\\file.txt" + "';";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

In this example, `driver` is your WebDriver instance.

Please note that you have to use four backslashes (`\`) for Windows-like paths because you are required to pass double back-slashes to the JavaScript so you have to escape both with two additional slashes. The other option is to use a forward slash (e.g. `"C:/tmp/file.txt"`) and that should also work.
Credits to the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307099/3485434)

Comment: As explained in the question, this does not work for me because there is no input element that accepts files. The upload button on the website is entirely custom, it's a button that calls some JavaScript to open a file dialog and uploads the file instantly once selected. There is no element for me to call `document.getElementById` on.

Comment: OK, I see. If you want I can remove this answer. Or I can leave it since it may be possibly helpful to other users

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation though I use rust Fantoccini with edge webdriver, trying to upload file to sharepoint.

There is only a "upload" button which triggers a OS uploading dialog.

However I found out that after clicking the "upload" button, an invisible input element was added to the dom which can be send_key by the webdriver.

This way I managed uploding the file though I don't know how to close the OS dialog.

[before click upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKWfA.png)

[after click upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmLYh.png)