# How to use Silverlight spy tool with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: silverlight, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, spy

I have downloaded free version of silverlight spy tool to capture object defitions of silverlight controls. I want to use these definitions into my script which I am executing using selenium web driver.

Could anyone help me on how to capture object definitions so that these can be used in Selenium webdriver framework.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium does not interact with Silverlight on its own. You will have to find a library, etc. that will allow you to interface with Silverlight and Selenium together. I found an old post that talks about one such library.

[How can automation testing on Silverlight using Selenium be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224943/how-can-automation-testing-on-silverlight-using-selenium-be-done)