# How to test silverlight application through selenium web driver and Java

Tags: silverlight, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using silver light application,

I have gone through the [Code Google](https://code.google.com/archive/p/silverlight-selenium/).

Can you please explain the actual details and which jar file i have to added.

Comment: Possibly you can find it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224943/how-can-automation-testing-on-silverlight-using-selenium-be-done)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to move to .NET you might look at [Telerik Testing Framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework). It's not open source, but it's free. It has great support for Silverlight and WPF applications.

I used to work at Telerik and loved the framework.